# why data retrieving slow on C# Entity-Framework Code first when used layered architecture..?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm developing C# Desktop application with using code first C# entity-framework technology. I need to use layered architecture with these layers on it.

1.Entity Layer - for code first db creation

2.Data Access Layer - for accessing db and all the db related methods are here

3.Business Logic layer - for connecting interface with data access layer

4.Presentation Layer - for interface designing

on getting data from database, it takes a while to load. is there any way to fix it...?

My project manager Prof said that it's because of the layered architecture....

Comment: Well whats slow? The data returned by the database? or the data returned by the UI??? And what's slow to you? <1s <10s <20s <1min?

Comment: Most likely you're thinking about freezing UI. DB operations should be invoked in tasks, that will improve user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any idea on your model it is impossible to say why data retrieval is slow. EF is somewhat slower than other ORM frameworks on .NET but it works fine. You should start analysing your model. Also, remember that you have a database behind your model. Users of ORM tools have tendency to forget about this. You can use something like [EF Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) to see the queries you are sending to your database server. This kind of tools is a must when using ORM over more or less complex model.

One typical issue is SELECT N+1 problem when you fetch an entity that has a collection of other entities, the collection is proxied and you start to loop through it, your child entities are lazy loaded one by one, issuing at least as many queries as you have those child entities. In this case eager fetchig is the key solution. But, again, you provided no details, so you have to figure out the issue yourself. And the problem is not EF as such and not layered architecture.

Comment: Thank you dear, got idea form this,